# Is orthogonal subspace to Eigen subspace another eigensubspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, self-learning, invariant-subspace

> Is Orthogonal subspace to eigen subspace another eigen subspace?

Say A is matrix. $\lambda$ is an eigen value and $U=E_{\lambda} $ is its corresponding eigen subspace. $U^{\perp}$ is another eigen subspace?

$Au = \lambda u , u \in E_{\lambda}\\ $

Now say $\vec v$ is another vector in orthogonal subspace to U. $v^Tu=0 \\ u^TAv = v^TAu = v^T(\lambda u) = 0$

It means $A \vec v$ is also perpendicular to $\vec u$.

It means $A \vec v$ lies in V(orthogonal subspace of $E_{\lambda}$). Would that mean that $A \vec v = \lambda' v$ ???? making V another eigen subspace for $\lambda'$. If V happened to be spanned by single vector then V becomes eigen subspace right? It can happen that V may be spanned by more than 1 vector. In that case Av though lies in V (orthogonal subspace), Av may not be equal to scaled version of $\vec v$(Only in scaled version of v vector right, we call that eigen subspace!?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in addition to the example GReyes gave of a $3\times 3$ matrix with only one eigenvalue, if you have a matrix with more than one eigenvalue then $U^{\perp}$ will contain **all** of the other eigenspaces and so will not usually itself be an eigenspace.

In fact for $U^{\perp}$ to be an eigenspace, the matrix must have precisely two eigenvalues, **and** be diagonalizable (ie there must exist a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ consisting entirely of eigenvectors).

Comment: Sir let me understand in bit detail.  $U^{\perp}$ is all union of orthogonal subspaces to $E_{\lambda}$? I was thinking each orthogonal subspace is one $U^{\perp}$

Comment: @NascimentodeCos No, $U^{\perp}$ is the orthogonal complement of $U$; there is not more than one $U^{\perp}$. Every vector orthogonal to $U$ is in $U^{\perp}$.

Comment: sir when matrix is diagonizable and symmetric, then eigen vectors are orthonomral to each other and form the basis. In that case Subspaces spanned by those eigen vectors are orthogonal to each other right? If n eigen vectors then n orthogonal eigen spaces. Similar analogy for $U^{\perp}$? pls correct me if wrong

Comment: @NascimentodeCos No, there are $n$ orthogonal eigenspaces when there are $n$ eigen**values**. And if $U$ is one of those eigenspaces, then $U^{\perp}$ contains **all** of the vectors orthogonal to $U$, so will contain all of the other eigenspaces (though will not in general be a union of the other eigenspaces).

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in general. Just consider a nontrivial rotation $\mathbb{R}^3$. The axis of rotation is an eigenspace with eigenvalue $1$, but the orthogonal complement is not a (real) eigenspace (there are no other real eigenvalues).